# How to implement Cascade on Delete Using Asp.coreBoilerplate Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to implement Cascade on delete functionality for asp.net core boilerplate. But I am unable to do so? Here is what I have done to do this.

Company is the parent Class:

```
  public class Company:FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeesCount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee is the Child Class which is having one to many relationship with the Company class.

```
public class Employees:FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Salaray { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have done in the Dbcontext class to implement Cascade on Delete functionality.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Company)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).HasForeignKey<Employees>(t=>t.CompanyId);
    }
```

But when I delete a record for the parent entity(Company) the relevant record from the child table(Employee) is not deleted.

Comment: Can you try modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Company)
            .WithMany(a => a.Employees)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Delete);?

Comment: You need to cascade soft deletes yourself. See [#3559](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/3559).